# Serving images asynchronously using django and celery?

Tags: django, image, celery, django-celery

I have a django app that serves images when a certain page is loaded. The images are stored on S3 and I retrieve them using boto and send the image content as an `HttpResponse` with the appropriate content type.

The problem here is, this is a blocking call. Sometimes, it takes a long time (few secs for the image of few hundred KBs)  to retrieve the images and serve them to the client.

I tried doing converting this process to a celery task (async, non-blocking), but I am not sure how I can send back the data (images) when they are done downloading. Just returning `HttpResponse` from a celery task does not work. I found docs related to http callback tasks in an old celery docs [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/userguide/remote-tasks.html), but this is not supported in the newer celery versions.

So, should I use polling in the js? (I have used celery tasks in other parts of my website, but all of them are socket based) or is this even the right way to approach the problem?

Code:

Django views code that fetches the images (from S3 using boto3): (in `views.py`)

```
@csrf_protect
@ensure_csrf_cookie
def getimg(request, public_hash):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        query = img_table.objects.filter(public_hash=public_hash)
    else:
        query = img_table.objects.filter(public_hash=public_hash, is_public=True)
    if query.exists():
        item_dir = construct_s3_path(s3_map_thumbnail_folder, public_map_hash)
        if check(s3, s3_bucket, item_dir): #checks if file exists
            item = s3.Object(s3_bucket, item_dir)
            item_content = item.get()['Body'].read()
            return HttpResponse(item_content, content_type="image/png",status=200)
        else: #if no image found, return a blank image
            blank = Image.new('RGB', (1000,1000), (255,255,255))
            response = HttpResponse(content_type="image/jpeg")
            blank.save(response, "JPEG")
            return response
    else: #if request image corresponding to hash is not found in db
        return render(request, 'core/404.html')
```

I call the above django view in a page like this:
`<img src='/api/getimg/123abc' alt='img'>`

In `urls.py` I have:
`url(r'^api/getimg/(?P<public_hash>[a-zA-Z0-9]{6})$', views.getimg, name='getimg')`